# Error with packages that cause OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, conda, torch

I'm trying to run the program main file however when installing torch and cuda there seems to be an error that pops up: "`OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application`"

I have already downgraded torch, torchvision and numpy

```
runfile('//nsq025vs/u10/aczc973/Desktop/MScProjectConvert/main.py', wdir='//nsq025vs/u10/aczc973/Desktop/MScProjectConvert')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-e4181834ff1d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('//nsq025vs/u10/aczc973/Desktop/MScProjectConvert/main.py', wdir='//nsq025vs/u10/aczc973/Desktop/MScProjectConvert')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "//nsq025vs/u10/aczc973/Desktop/MScProjectConvert/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import numpy as _np

  File "\\nsq025ps\p10\aczc973\AppData\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init

  File "\\nsq025ps\p10\aczc973\AppData\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mix between differnt python installations: `C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages` and `\\nsq025ps\p10\aczc973\AppData\Python\Python37\site-packages` which probably have a different 32/64bit setup. Make sure that your PYTHONPATH does not include the reference to `\\nsq025ps\p10\aczc973\AppData\Python\Python37\site-packages` when you are running stuff with your `anaconda` distribution and vice versa.

Even safer: Completely uninstall `\\nsq025ps\p10\aczc973\AppData\Python\Python37`, you should not need a python installation besides your `anaconda`